# Почему использование статического логгера в spring плохо?

Tags: spring, логирование, static

Написал один статический класс- обертку для логгера пишущего в различные файлы. Создал  интерфейс вызывающий методы статического класса. Заставил все бины наследовать данный интерфейс.
Специалисты по spring говорят так делать нельзя. Почему, не объясняют.

Comment: Нельзя делать - когда компилятор говорит что нельзя, а все остальное можно. Вопрос в целесообразности. Если люди не пояснили суть "нельзя", то слушать их, мне кажется, не самая лучшая затея.

Comment: Покажите код. Из объяснения непонятно что вы сделали. В такой формулировке на вопрос не ответить - не достаточно конкретики.